# Nestjs terminus gRPC health checks

Tags: nestjs, health-check

my issue is on the terminus module, I installed using:

```
yarn add @nestjs/terminus
```

And the I added the TerminusModule to my main module. But when I try to do a yarn start:dev to work with this, I just keep getting the following error:

```
    [Nest] 18136  - 05/05/2023, 11:57:32 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the TypeOrmHealthIndicator (?). Please make sure that the argument ModuleRef at index [0] is available in the TerminusModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is TerminusModule a valid NestJS module?
- If ModuleRef is a provider, is it part of the current TerminusModule?
- If ModuleRef is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within TerminusModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing ModuleRef */ ]
  })
```

Now I do not have typeOrm installed on this application as this application doesn't need or use that, so is it a force requirement to install this package and have it declared on my modules? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank yo all in advance.

Comment: were you able to solve that?